# Scanf affects another variable, a bug?

Tags: c, gcc, scanf, mingw

Here is a simple C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char choice;
    int condition = 0;

    while (condition < 3)
    {
        printf("Type in a number: ");
        scanf("%hhd", &choice);        
        condition++;        
        printf("%d\n", condition);
    }
}
```

I expect this to increment my `condition` variable each time a type in a character. But all of a sudden the output looks like this:

```
Type in a number: 1
1
Type in a number: 2
1
Type in a number: 3
1
Type in a number: 4
1
Type in a number: 5
1
Type in a number: 6
1
Type in a number: 7
1
Type in a number:
```

The problem goes away if I comment out `scanf("%hhd", &choice);`. How can it be? A bug?
I have `gcc 8.1.0` by `mingw-w64`.

Everything works well with `clang`, I just wonder why it is this way with `gcc`.

---

I have placed `void` as a parameter of `main` and it has solved the problem. Why?

Comment: `"%hhd"` expects a pointer to an `int` but you provide a `char` pointer. I guess it is located before your `int condition` which then gets overwritten. What happens if you change `char choice` to `int choice` ?

Comment: @Yes, it works,, but it goes even stranger when I instead add `void` to `main`, because this also solves the problem

Comment: @StefanRiedel `%hhd` is for char `%hd` for short

Comment: @0___________ is more likely for `short short int` which is the same size as `char` I guess

Comment: @StefanRiedel `%hdd` is for `signed char`, to be exact: https://godbolt.org/z/1dq83Wrx6

Comment: What if you declare `choice` as `signed char`?

Comment: oh my bad, you're right

Comment: Probably something to do with limited support for format specifiers in the mingw environment. Work in mine btw, but weirdly, not flushing the output even with added `\n`.

Comment: @Kaiyakha maybe your implementation of the standard library does support all print formats. It is quite common issue especially if the library is ported to smaller uP or uCs

Comment: There is an update to the question as well

Comment: @Kaiyakha upgrade your compiler and library

Comment: @Kaiyakha what is `short short int`? Answer : invalid syntax

Comment: @0___________ everything works well with `clang`, I just wonder why it is this way with `gcc`

Comment: @0___________ 1-byte integer, wrong notation of course, but this is how you can read `hhd`

Comment: Addressing the edited comment regarding `int main(void)`.  In appendix J.2, it is explicitly stated that the behavior is undefined for programs which fail to conform to one of the appropriate declarations of main (either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.  This is a good example.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, thanks, that seems to be an answer, but please share the link

Comment: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your C library might not be implementing the `%hhd` specifier for `scanf` correctly.

I tried this test fragment on my machine:

```
char a[] = "abcdef";
scanf("%hhd", &a[3]);
```

I typed `88`, and the string changed to `abcXef`, confirming that `%hhd` wrote to just one byte of memory, as expected.

I don't see anything overtly wrong with the code you posted. On my machine, it prompts for just three inputs, because the `condition` variable increments correctly.